# Exporting from Atlas to PDF in QGIS GUI and adding metadata with Python

Tags: pyqgis, metadata, atlas

I'm trying to add metadata to all my PDF files generated by an Atlas export in QGIS 3.10. GUI.

Is there any Python signal to which I can connect a slot, that gets executed when each Atlas page export finishes?

Unfortunately, studying the PyQGIS API documentation didn't take me any further.